# Como percorrer uma ou mais table html e suas table html filhas?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como percorrer todas as tabelas e suas tabelas filhas, pois preciso fazer uma somatória das colunas "Valor" ? 
As tabelas são criadas dinamicamente de acordo com o retorno da função Ajax. 
Posso ter 1 ou mais tabelas "pai" e para cada tabela "pai" posso ter uma ou mais tabelas "Filhas".

Sei que percorrer uma table poderia fazer assim:

```
$("#btnSavar").on("click", function(){
    $('#tblEmpresa> tbody  > tr').each(function() { 
       var linha = $(this);
    });
});
```

Porém preciso percorrer **todas a tabelas e suas tabelas filhas** a partir de um único evento do botão, mas não sei como percorrer essas tabelas filhas:

**Table:**

```
<div id="divPrincipal>
    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-title">Empresa A</div>
        <div class="ibox-content" id="acordion">
            <table id=tblEmpresa data-IdTblEmpresa=1>
                <thead><th>Nome</th><th>Endereco</th><th>Telefone</th><th>Valor Empresa</th></thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>R$ 3000,00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=3>
                            <table id=tblProduto data-IdTblProduto=43>
                                <thead><th>Nome</th><th>Tipo</th><th>Valor Produto</th></thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>R$ 17,00</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>R$ 86,00</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>R$ 71,00</td>
                                    </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>  
    
    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-title">Empresa B</div>
        <div class="ibox-content" id="acordion">
            <table id=tblEmpresa data-IdTblEmpresa=2>
                <thead><th>Nome</th><th>Endereco</th><th>Telefone</th><th>Valor Empresa</th></thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>R$ 500,00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=3>
                            <table id=tblProduto data-IdTblProduto=21>
                                <thead><th>Nome</th><th>Tipo</th><th>Valor Produto</th></thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>R$ 20,99</td>
                                    </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-title">Empresa C</div>
        <div class="ibox-content" id="acordion">
            <table id=tblEmpresa data-IdTblEmpresa=3>
                <thead><th>Nome</th><th>Endereco</th><th>Telefone</th><th>Valor Empresa</th></thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>R$ 250,00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=3>
                            <table id=tblProduto data-IdTblProduto=35>
                                <thead><th>Nome</th><th>Tipo</th><th>Valor Produto</th></thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>R$ 54,90</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>R$ 38,00</td>
                                    </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Voce quer pegar todos os valores ? E somar?

Comment: se as tag <table> filhas tiverem uma referência (*seja class, id, etc*) você pode percorrer-las utilizando ```forEach()``` ou contando-as com um laço ```for``` ai a partir da *Index* de cara <table> filha você pode ta obtendo os valores (sugiro que vá adicionando-os em um Array) e ao final do laço somar tudo!

Comment: @novic quero pegar o valor total de cada table, Valor total da table1 Pai, depois pegar o Valor da Table1 filha, pegar Valor Total da table2 e assim por diante.

Comment: Você recebe um JSON? porque eu vi você dizer AJAX, se sim soma por ele é o ideal

Comment: sim @novic recebo um JSON, poderia fazer a soma no momento do carregamento da tela, porém isto não basta pois o usuário pode remover ou adicionar novos itens daí então que preciso percorrer as tabelas sempre que o usuário clicar no botão btnSalvar.

Comment: Não precisa fazer só no carregamento, se ele adicionar valores dinâmicos adicione um variavel o valor para mostrar na tela! porque mesmo ele adicionando você vai ter que atualizar o valor